# Datastore get last inserted id with Node

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, datastore

How does one get the last inserted entity's ID in datastore using node?

Doc says to insert like this:

```
datastore.insert(entity)
  .then(result) => {
    // Task inserted successfully.
  });
```

From this, inspecting the returned `result` object,
the only way i found was going through the object like this

```
result[0].mutationResults[0].key.path[0].id
```

This seems brittle and unreliable. If in the future the structure of the returned object breaks, the app breaks.

Is this the right way to do it in node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I may have answered my own question.

Inside the `then` callback, I indeed have to do `result[0].mutationResults[0].key.path[0].id`

However, I can target the entity as well, like so

```
const userEntity = {
  email: 'foo@foo.com',
  passwd: 'secret'
}

ds.insert(userEntity)
  .then(result) => {
    return userEntity.key.id
    // or, result[0].mutationResults[0].key.path[0].id
  }
```

Comment: doesn't `userEntity.key.id` only work if you set the key beforehand? (before insertion)